# Haskell how to append integer like ".. ++ Integer ++ ..."

Tags: haskell, append, type-conversion

Here is my code:

```
func :: Integer -> String
func i = "LoadC R" ++ i ++ "\n"
```

But I got the error:

> Couldn't match expected type `[Char]' with actual type `Integer'

How do I convert `i` to char?

Comment: Use `show`, `"LoadC R" ++ show i ++ "\n"`.

Comment: thanks, it works! but how do i print a new line?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Use `show` to turn a number into a string:

```
func :: Integer -> String
func i = "LoadC R" ++ show i ++ "\n"
```

`show` works on lots of things (but not all).
To actually print this, you need to do

```
main = putStr (func 5)
```

or if you're using ghci (which I would recommend you use a *lot* while you write your code, testing everything as soon as you've written it), you can just write

```
putStr (func 5)
```

and it will work. (I'll explain why below.)

If you use `putStrLn` instead of `putStr` it puts an extra newline at the end.
If you want a new line in what you're printing, put `\n` in it wherever you like.

```
func2 :: Integer -> String
func2 i = "\nLoadC \nR\n" ++ show i ++ "\n"
```

has lots of newlines in it.

Why does `putStr` turn `\n` into newlines? Well, `putStr` and `putStrLn` have type `String -> IO ()` meaning they turn the String they're given into an IO program that puts it on the screen. In ghci, if you give it something of type `IO ()`, it'll do it. If you give it something of another type it'll `show` it and then `putStr` that. This means that if you type

```
"Hello\nMum"
```

it has the same effect as

```
putStrLn (show "Hello\nMum")
```

whereas if you wanted the `\n` to be a newline, you'd need to do

```
putStrLn "Hello\nMum"
```

to stop ghci from `show`ing it before putting it on the screen. (If you find yourself doing a lot of `putStr (show x)`, there's a shortcut: `print x`.)

Comment: Thanks. I run the program by "func 5". How do I print a new line?

Comment: @user1510412 hope the new edit explains a bit better for you.